# Bootstrap Filter Table not showing select option

Tags: html, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4

I just used a script and Html from a [codepen](https://codepen.io/AurelieT/pen/JGxMgo) code in my apps-script. Table appears but two thing does not appear 1st the select and search option under Table Head. Second exporter.

Exporter is not that much important. However I need those select and input search option under Table head.

Here is a screenshot of Original table from code pen:-
[image]

And here is screenshot of my Apps-script html:-

[image]

here is the complete HTml code of apps script:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
     
  <?!= include('table-css'); ?>
  <?!= include('table-js'); ?> 
    
  </head>
  <body>
        
<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap Table</h1>
<p> Mémo pour les options du Bootstrap Table : <a href="http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/">Bootstrap Table Documentation</a></p>
<p>Eléments de Bootstrap Table utilisés : <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/3178/">Data Checkbox</a>, pour cocher les éléments à sélectionner, <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/extensions/filter-control.html">extension Filter control</a>, pour les filtres via les colonnes, <a href="https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin">extension Data export</a> pour exporter</p>

<div id="toolbar">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">Export Basic</option>
                <option value="all">Export All</option>
                <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
        </select>
</div>

<table id="table" 
             data-toggle="table"
             data-search="true"
             data-filter-control="true" 
             data-show-export="true"
             data-click-to-select="true"
             data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Prénom</th>
            <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
            <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Examen</th>
            <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valérie</td>
            <td>01/09/2015</td>
            <td>Français</td>
            <td>12/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="1" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>05/09/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>8/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="2" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>05/09/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>4/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="3" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valérie</td>
            <td>05/09/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>10/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="4" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>01/09/2015</td>
            <td>Français</td>
            <td>14/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="5" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valérie</td>
            <td>07/09/2015</td>
            <td>Mathématiques</td>
            <td>19/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="6" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>01/09/2015</td>
            <td>Français</td>
            <td>11/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="7" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>01/10/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>8/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="8" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>07/09/2015</td>
            <td>Mathématiques</td>
            <td>14/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="9" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valérie</td>
            <td>01/10/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>12/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="10" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>07/09/2015</td>
            <td>Mathématiques</td>
            <td>14/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="11" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>01/10/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>10/20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>       

  </body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script>
  init({
    title: 'Filter Control',
    desc: 'Use Plugin: bootstrap-table-filter-control to filter table fields.',
    links: [
      'bootstrap-table.min.css'
    ],
    scripts: [
      'bootstrap-table.min.js',
      'extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js'
    ]
  })
</script>

</html>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share how are you executing it? Share all the scripts and manifest file without personal information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about `init()` in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.17.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

#### To:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.17.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.17.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
```

#### Reference:

- [bootstrap-table in cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-table)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tanaike, I sent you an email on your hotmail id long time ago but I guess you have not read it.